# What is the Java equivalent for formatting of the following string?

Tags: c#, java, string, formatting, console

I am porting c# code to Java and is having troubles with conversion of the following code so that the **string format** being written to the console is exactly the same. What is the java equivalent for the following c# code?

```
byte b = 0xFF;
Console.Write("{0,04:X2}", b);
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to include what that C# code would emit?

Comment: @Adam Paynter: It outputs [space][space]FF, where spaces are padding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
byte b = (byte) 0xFF;
System.out.printf("%4X", b);
```

Output:

```
  FF
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to type-cast the assignment value i.e. byte b = (byte)0xFF; looks to work.
to print it into console, simply use System.out.printf("%X", b);

Comment: I don't think this answers his question. He is trying to _format_ that byte.